# How do I link JS file from other folder to a page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I downloaded some realtime css editor and I have a hard time figuring out how to link it to my other pages.

I have a file called cssit.js (that's a css editor) and if I put it in a same folder as my page, it works fine. However, if I wish to link to that script from pages that are in other folders, I don't know how to.

Example: My page is in images/index.php, but that script is in scripts/javascript/cssit.js

How would I link to index.php that script?

Comment: You can use two dots `../` to come back up a level, but why is your index page in an images folder?

Comment: Just use relative paths? If the images and scripts are in the same folder, you will simply have to (1) traverse one directory up, (2) navigate to scripts > javascript and (3) load cssit.js, like: `../scripts/javascript/cssit.js`

Comment: @Andy Every folder can have it's index page. And you don't have to write name of a page in a URL when you accessing it, only folder name

Comment: Yes, I appreciate that (RESTful APIs etc.) it just seems odd  that it would be used with an images folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// images/index.php    
<script src="../scripts/javascript/cssit.js">

// another/dir/index.php
<script src="../../scripts/javascript/cssit.js">
```

Or, maybe an easier way is to use absolute paths. Assuming `scripts/javascript` is at the root of your website:

```
// images/index.php
<script src="/scripts/javascript/cssit.js">

// another/dir/index.php
<script src="/scripts/javascript/cssit.js">
```